# How to position certain text to right despite text-content being set to center?

Tags: html, css

I am making a web GUI, and I want to add a close button, but here's the problem: it is being centered.

here's a portion of CSS:

```css
.modmenu-container { 
  text-align: center;
}

.close-btn {
  top:0;
  right:0;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: What does the HTML code look like?

Comment: Simplest would be to put your button inside a container of its own, with the container styled with `text-align: right;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the properties: top, right, bottom, and left can only be used when a position is not static. Static is the default position for every element, however, you can change it with the [position](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj6lrmF4fz6AhVOElkFHY7eD_4QFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Fposition&usg=AOvVaw2FFc5t6zxL7lglQmPh88Yc) property. This can sometimes mess things up, so to fix that, we can set the parent's (`.modmenu-container`) position to relative. Then we can set the button's position to absolute and position it to the top right.

```css
.modmenu-container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); /* For demonstration */
  padding: 1em; /* Demonstration */
  width: 40vw; /* Demonstration */
  height: 40vh; /* Demonstration */
  text-align: center;
 }
.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Demonstration */
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="modmenu-container">
 <button class="close-btn">
   &times;
  </button>
 Content here
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- set parent position to relative

2- set button position to absolute

3- use top, right, left and bottom to position the button.

```css
.modmenu-container { 
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="modmenu-container">Hello there
  <button class="close-btn">X</button>
 </div>
```